# How to group nested maps

Tags: java, java-stream

My current attempt:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> collect = shopping.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap/*groupingBy? */(e -> e.getKey().getAge(),
                    e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b.getKey().getCategory(), Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)))));
```

`shopping` is basically a map: `Map<Client, Map<Product,Integer>>`,

The problem comes from the fact that the provided data **contains multiple values by key** - there are Clients with same ages, and the code works only for a single value by key.

How could I make this code work also for multiple keys?

I suppose it should be somehow changed to use collect `collect(Collectors.groupingBy)` ->

in the resulting map  `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>`:

- The outer key (Integer) represents the client age.
- The inner key (String) - represents product category
- The inner maps value (Integer) - represents the number of products
  which belong to a specific category.

My attempt using groupingBy:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> collect = shopping.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(/*...*/))
```

Simply I want to refactor that code into one using streams:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> counts = new HashMap<>();

 for (Map.Entry<Client, Map<Product, Integer>> iData : shopping.entrySet()) {
      int age = iData.getKey().getAge();
      for (Map.Entry<Product, Integer> iEntry : iData.getValue().entrySet()) {
        String productCategory = iEntry.getKey().getCategory();
        counts.computeIfAbsent(age, (agekey) -> new HashMap<>()).compute(productCategory, (productkey, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want to handle Clients having the same age?

Comment: That's the question. I'd gladly know the answer

Comment: basically the values for same ages should be merged together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more appropriate via a `groupingBy` collector instead of `toMap`.

```
 Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> result = shopping.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getAge(),
                        flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().keySet().stream(),
                            groupingBy(Product::getCategory,
                                    summingInt(e -> 1)))));
```

note this uses `flatMapping` which is only available in the standard library as of jdk9.

Comment: There's a problem here. Key is a Client with such members as: firstname, lname, age and cash. In your 2nd Collectors.groupingBy you collect the data by e -> e.getKey().getCategory().  In resultant  Map <Integer, Map <String, Integer> the key <Integer> is Client age, String is Product category, and integer here indicates the number of products which belong to that category

Comment: @Ares02 to further clarify your question, update the post with the models you're using and also show the result you're currently getting with your imperative approach which may involve providing some sample data to work with. in the meantime I've updated the post to work on the `Product` category as you've mentioned.

Comment: It works perfectly fine now. Anyway not sure, why there is e->1 in Collectors.summingInt(e->1)

Comment: @Ares02 you can think of `groupingBy(Product::getCategory,
                                        summingInt(e -> 1))` as `groupingBy(Product::getCategory,
                                        counting())` the only difference being the resulting type returned by the former `summingInt` is `Integer` and the latter `counting` is `Long`. in other words  `summingInt(e->1) ` gets the count for each product category.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks. Basically the method should find the most Popular Category By Clients Age and return  a Map < Integer, String>. I' m just curious if is it possible to "merge" your code into the one finding the Category with maximum value - products bought. I' ll make a new answer to proive the rest of my code

Comment: @Ares02 this answer already answeres the problem in the question. if you have new requirements **consider asking a new question** **and** please go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as I had to edit your post to make it a little better than it was.

Answer (score 2):

A non-stream(`forEach`) way to convert your for loop could be :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> counts = new HashMap<>();
shopping.forEach((key, value1) -> value1.keySet().forEach(product ->
        counts.computeIfAbsent(key.getAge(),
                (ageKey) -> new HashMap<>())
                .merge(product.getCategory(), 1, Integer::sum)));
```

Comment: Instead of `compute` you could use `merge(product.getCategory(), 1, Integer::sum)`